# TCPDF how to disable font italic?

Tags: php, css, tcpdf

i'm using TCPDF library for generate PDF file, but i have problem with disabling font italic. I'm using writeHTML and have local css with body{font-style:normal;} but it's doesn't work.

Ok, i solved this problem.

I have twice

```
$pdf->SetFont('freeserif', '', 14, '', false);
$pdf->SetFont('times', 'BI', 20);
```

Comment: share your code.

Comment: Did you try `body{font-style:normal !important;}`?

Comment: My fault i have twice

Comment: $pdf->SetFont('freeserif', '', 14, '', false);
$pdf->SetFont('times', 'BI', 20);

Comment: But good to know, i didn't try use !important

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$pdf->SetFont('times', 'BI', 20);
```

From [Fonts](https://tcpdf.org/docs/fonts/):

> `SetFont(string family[,string style[,string size]])`
>
> style : Font style. Possible values are (case insensitive):
>
> - empty string: regular
> - B: bold
> - **I: italic**
> - U: underline
>
> or any combination. The default value is regular.